# Evaluating $\int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2 \log^2(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})} \,dx\,dy.$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> $$\int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2 \log^2(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})} \,dx\,dy.$$

I encountered this integral while evaluating norm of a function. The first attempt was to change it into polar coordinates, which didn't work well, since the region of integration is rectangular.

I found a similar integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122698/double-integral-help-int-x-0-5x-1-5-int-0-50-5-fracdx-dy-sqrt), but even [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a)  couldn't calculate this.

Does anybody know how to evaluate this?

Comment: More than likely of no use; numerical integration leads to $0.19498316 \cdots$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Comment: What is the point of computing a closed form for such integral? If you need an approximation for the norm of a function, you may use numerical methods; if you need inequalities, you may exploit the fact that the integration domain (the square) contains and is contained in a circle with a suitable radius.

Comment: Also, by symmetry such integral can be simply written as $$ \frac{1}{2}\iint_{(-1/2,1/2)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2)\log^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}= 2\iint_{(0,1/2)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2)\log^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know. It's just that I encountered this integral and for a moment, I thought, well it's easily integrable, but then I saw the domain and realized it's not easy at all. So, I just wanted to know if there is a technique that I should know. It's good to learn, right?

Answer (score 1):

We may tackle the equivalent integral

$$ \mathcal{J}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2)\log^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)} $$
by writing it as
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}\rho}{\rho^2\log^2\left(\rho/4\right)}\,d\rho +\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arccos\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\rho}{\rho^2\log^2(\rho/4)}\,d\rho$$
which equals
$$ \frac{\pi}{3\log 2}-2\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\arccos\frac{1}{\rho}}{\rho \log^2(\rho/4)}\,d\rho=\frac{\pi}{3\log 2}-2\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{1}\frac{\arccos\rho}{\rho\log^2(4\rho)}\,d\rho $$
or
$$ \frac{\pi}{6\log 2}+2\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{1}\frac{\arcsin\rho}{\rho\log^2(4\rho)}\,d\rho = \frac{\pi}{3\log 2}-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\theta\tan\theta}{\log^2(4\cos\theta)}\,d\theta.$$
The last integral is very far from being elementary or expressible through a simple hypergeometric series, but $\frac{\theta\tan\theta}{\log^2(4\cos\theta)}$ approximately behaves like $C\theta^4$ on $(0,\pi/4)$, hence the composite [Boole's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoolesRule.html) provides excellent numerical approximations with few computations. We get
$$ \mathcal{J}\approx 1.239117616448\approx \frac{35725}{28831}. $$